# ¿Se ha planteado incluir en el DLE las expresiones de Chiquito de la Calzada? ¿Por qué?

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones, dle

Nos llega hoy la (para mí) triste [noticia de la muerte de Chiquito de la Calzada](https://elpais.com/cultura/2017/11/11/actualidad/1510356335_044866.html). *Sit tibi terra levis*, maestro.

Más allá de que su humor nos pudiera hacer gracia o no, es innegable su impacto en la manera de hablar de todo un país.
Palabros como "fistro", "diodenal", "agromenauer", "jarl"... y expresiones como "por la gloria de mi madre" o "pecador de la pradera" pasaron a formar parte de la jerga popular de 40 millones de personas; y otras palabras, aunque ya las sabíamos, se nos hacían nuevas cuando las colaba él en algún chiste. Véase por ejemplo [el resurgir de "cobarde" desde mediados de los 90](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cobarde&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccobarde%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcobarde%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCobarde%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Ccobarde%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcobarde%3B%2Cc1%3B%3BCobarde%3B%2Cc0) (Chiquito empezó a salir por televisión en 1994).
No muchos paisanos pueden jactarse de algo así.

Lo cual me lleva, en parte por curiosidad y en parte como homenaje, a plantear mi pregunta: **¿se ha llegado a plantear de manera seria la inclusión en el DLE, como nueva palabra (por ej. "fistro") o como nueva acepción (de por ej. "torpedo"), de alguna de las expresiones que usaba Chiquito de la Calzada?** ¿Qué argumentos podrían darse a favor o en contra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En [**FUNDEU**](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/el-reto-linguistico-de-lograr-que-fistro-sobreviva-a-chiquito/) analizan la posibilidad de que **fistro** sea incluido en el DLE:

> El reto lingüístico de lograr que «fistro» sobreviva a Chiquito
>   Chiquito de la Calzada se ha ido y nos ha dejado sus chistes y
>   expresiones inventadas. Estas ya forman parte de la jerga española,
>   pero corren el riesgo de desaparecer. El principal problema es que más
>   de veinte años después, **nadie sabe aún qué es un fistro**.
>
> Académicos y lingüistas consultados por Sinc dudan de las
>   posibilidades de supervivencia de esta palabra en la lengua
>   castellana.
>
> ... Chiquito de la Calzada, contó en 1994 durante su debut
>   televisivo. Era la primera vez que España escuchaba una palabra que
>   sería repetida durante años sin que nadie supiera qué significaba ni
>   de dónde había salido. Ahora que el humorista malagueño nos ha dejado,
>   ¿desaparecerá también su fistro?
>
> Varias campañas de Change.org ya piden la inclusión de fistro en el
>   diccionario de la RAE, pero los expertos consultados por Sinc dudan
>   que sobreviva. **«Es muy difícil que una palabra de este tipo entre en
>   la lengua, aunque no significa que sea imposible», asegura Javier
>   Bezos, uno de los miembros de la Fundación del Español Urgente (Fundéu
>   BBVA). «Depende de que pase de una generación a otra, algo que en este
>   caso no parece que esté ocurriendo».**
>
> **«Creo que será difícil la supervivencia de fistro porque está muy
>   ligado a un origen y un contexto muy concretos, que cada vez resultan
>   más lejanos y extraños a los hablantes, en especial a las nuevas
>   generaciones»**, explica a Sinc el sociolingüista Francisco Moreno, que
>   es director del Instituto Cervantes en la Universidad de Harvard
>   (EEUU).

En resumen:
1) Si se ha planteado la inclusión en el DLE, al menos de **fistro**  [(**diferentes propuestas en change.org**)](https://www.change.org/search?q=fistro)
2) No es imposible, pero si muy difícil, dependiendo fundamentalmente de que pase de una generación a otra (en la línea de lo contestado por @Aurelio)

Answer (score 2):

En principio no veo por qué no, si es que su uso perdura y no es una *moda pasajera*. Al menos ese el argumento que dió la RAE hace años (no dispongo de fuentes, pero lo escuché en vivo y en directo en su momento) cuando se planteó si incluirían en [**carroza**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7irKN7s) la acepción

> 5. f. coloq. Persona vieja o anticuada. U. t. c. s. m. y f. U. t. c. adj.

y finalmente la incluyeron en el año 2001.

Comment: ¿Lo escuchaste en vivo y en directo? ¿En la RAE? ¡Dime que por fin se nos ha registrado en el sitio un académico! :-)

Comment: @Charlie: Lo siento, sin duda me he expresado mal. Lo escuché en una entrevista "en vivo y en directo" de televisión al (creo recordar) Director de la RAE allá por los años 80

Comment: Estaba bromeando, imaginaba que lo habrías visto en televisión o algo así. En todo caso si la entrevista se refería al vocabulario de Chiquito debió ser más tarde, ya que este saltó a la fama en 1994.

Comment: @Charlie: no, la pregunta era concretamente sobre la palabra "carroza", que empezaba a ponerse moda con ese significado no recogido en la RAE - por eso calculo que debía ser a principios de los 80.

Comment: Tienes razón, no había entendido bien la respuesta y posterior comentario. Mis disculpas. :-)

Comment: @Charlie: Igual que hay un Tranlation-Golf ¿qué tal un  "Resumen-Golf" buscando resumir un texto sin que pierda el significado? 
Por ejemplo:
>Apenas había el rubicundo Apolo tendido por la faz de la ancha y espaciosa tierra las doradas hebras de sus hermosos cabellos, y apenas los pequeños y pintados pajarillos con sus arpadas lenguas habían saludado con dulce y meliflua armonía la venida de la rosada aurora, que, dejando la blanda cama del celoso marido, por las puertas y balcones del manchego horizonte a los mortales se mostraba,   

podría resumirse como:  
>Amanecía en La Mancha

Comment: Al final es prácticamente lo que hacemos, tratar de resumir lo más posible además de traducir. Lo que propones se ha barajado alguna vez (buen texto y buen ejemplo). Te recomendamos que te pases por el chat [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) y expongas allí tus ideas, que serán bienvenidas, dado que los comentarios a una respuesta no son el sitio para debatir.